# Android Java Adding a single dimesional byte array to a double dimension byte array

Tags: java

I have a requirement to append another byte array(one dimensional) to existing byte array which happens to be two dimensional.

```
public static byte[][] ALL_MESSAGES = new byte[][] {SMART_POSTER_NO_TEXT, ENGLISH_PLAIN_TEXT, SMART_POSTER_URL_AND_TEXT};

public void AddOtherMessages()
{
    OtherMessageClass messages = new OtherMessageClass();

    for(NMessage m : messages.Ntexts)
    {
        ArrayUtil.addAll(ALL_MESSAGES, m);
    }

}
```

Obviously the code above does not work because I am using the AddAll to add two arrays, one a multidimensional, to another, a single dimension array.  I need some help with appending the **m** to ALL_MESSAGES please.

Also, what Java Namespace do I need to import to be able to do this?

Comment: Download `org.apache.commons.lang API`.  `ArrayUtils.addAll()` method requires *array parameters* must be `one` dimensional.

Comment: Really, what I am looking for is a sort of append/add functionality that will allow me add additional single-dimension byte arrays to the double-dimension byte array there.

Comment: Not possible with **arrays** unless you use `List<Byte>` or something like.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayUtil is a part of 'org.apache.commons.lang' package. So you,ll also have to include the corressponding jar file to use the same.

> You will require apache-commons-lang.jar and you will have to import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils. For more details refer http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

```
    for(NMessage m : messages.Ntexts)
    {
        ArrayUtil.addAll(ALL_MESSAGES, m);
    }
```

the above code will work not work m is not a byte[][]. If m is byte[] you should use 'add()' method instead. if messages.Ntexts returns byte[][] you could also use 'addAll()' method.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want to add extra arrays to `ALL_MESSAGES`? In that case, i think you should consider using a List:

```
List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
```

then you can add as many `byte[]` arrays as you like:

```
list.add(new byte[] {1,2,3}); //just an example
```

and you can just as easily retrieve them all:

```
for(byte [] array : list)
{
    //do whatever you like with your individual arrays
}
```

You can also get a single element (like you would with the index operator):

```
byte [] array = list.get(0);
```